# Setting draw-order (like matplotlib zorder) for multi-trace/multi-y-axes figure

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have a simple `graph_objects.Figure()` with multiple traces and multiple y-axes. Each axis has a single trace (time average of underlying data) with a corresponding min-max area below showing the range of the data.

Problem is that the shaded area coming from the min-max data starts to hide the important trace when I plot more than 1-2, see image below:

[image]

It seems to me that the draw order is decided by the axis-number, first `yaxis1`, then `yaxis2` etc., but I would really like to specify that all "shaded area" traces stay at the bottom, making the lines clear and always 100 % visible.

What I have tried:

- Style parameter `zIndex`: not accepted by `graph_objects.Scatter`
- Tie the "shaded area traces" to the first axis, but then they are plotted using that axis range of y-values, leading to a completely wrong result.
- Reducing the opacity: last resort solution

So, is this possible using Plotly Dash?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a [3D figure](https://plotly.com/python/3d-charts/) instead?

Comment: As a secondary solution you could take a look at Dash and switching the data depending on the user discretion, see some of the [examples](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing).